# The orientation of the rear camera is inverse portrait

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, camera, android-camera

I'm trying to switch the camera with a button and i'm also successul in that but the proble is that the preview of the rear camera is in inverse portrait i've tryied the setDiplayOrientation, but no changes... Maybe i've put it in a wrong line this is the code and with the button i call the start camera method:

```android
public class MainRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
    public static final String TAG = "MainRenderer";

    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 0;
    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_PORTRAIT = 1;
    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2;
    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_LANDSCAPE = 3;
    private Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo;
    public volatile int deviceOrientation = DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    private FSDK.HTracker tracker;

    private int[] textures;

    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
    private boolean updateSurfaceTexture = false;

    private FSDK.FSDK_Features[] trackingFeatures;
    private MR.MaskFeatures maskCoords;
    private int[] isMaskTexture1Created = new int[]{0};
    private int[] isMaskTexture2Created = new int[]{0};

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private ByteBuffer pixelBuffer;

    private FSDK.HImage cameraImage = new FSDK.HImage();
    private FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE cameraImageMode = new FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE();
    private FSDK.HImage snapshotImage = new FSDK.HImage();
    private FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE snapshotImageMode = new FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE();

    private MainView mainView;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    private volatile boolean isResizeCalled = false;
    private volatile boolean isResized = false;

    public long IDs[] = new long[MR.MAX_FACES];
    public long face_count[] = new long[1];

    private long frameCount = 0;
    private long startTime = 0;

    private AtomicBoolean isTakingSnapshot = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static final int[][] MASKS = new int[][]{
            {R.raw.lips_pink, R.drawable.lips_pink, R.drawable.lips_pink_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
            {R.raw.lips_purple, R.drawable.lips_purple, R.drawable.lips_purple_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
            {R.raw.lips_red, R.drawable.lips_red, R.drawable.lips_red_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
    };

    private int mask = 0;
    private int maskLoaded = 0;
    private volatile boolean isMaskChanged = false;
    private boolean inPreview = false;

    public void changeMask(int i) {
        mask += i;
        isMaskChanged = true;
    }

    public MainRenderer(MainView view) {
        tracker = Application.tracker;

        mainView = view;
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) mainView.getContext();

        trackingFeatures = new FSDK.FSDK_Features[MR.MAX_FACES];
        for (int i = 0; i < MR.MAX_FACES; ++i) {
            trackingFeatures[i] = new FSDK.FSDK_Features();
            for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                trackingFeatures[i].features[j] = new FSDK.TPoint();
            }
        }
        maskCoords = new MR.MaskFeatures();
    }

    public void close() {
        updateSurfaceTexture = false;
        surfaceTexture.release();
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        deleteTex();
    }

    public void startCamera() {
        if (inPreview) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            inPreview = false;
        }
        //NB: if you don't release the current camera before switching, you app will crash
        camera.release();

        //swap the id of the camera to be used
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            cameraInfo.facing = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        } else {
            cameraInfo.facing = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        }
        camera = Camera.open(cameraInfo.facing);
        //Code snippet for this method from somewhere on android developers, i forget where
        //setCameraDisplayOrientation(mainActivity, cameraInfo.facing, camera);
        try {
            //this step is critical or preview on new camera will no know where to render to
            camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
        inPreview = true;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) { //call opengl functions only inside these functions!
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        isResizeCalled = false;
        isResized = false;

        initTex();
        loadMask(mask);

        surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textures[0]);
        surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

        // Find the ID of the camera
        int cameraId = 0;
        boolean frontCameraFound = false;
        cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            }
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                frontCameraFound = true;
            }
        }

        if (frontCameraFound) {
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }

        try {
            camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GLES11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //background color
    }

    private byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 16384;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }

    // must be called from the thread with OpenGL context!
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    public void loadMask(int maskNumber) {
        GLES11.glDisable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);

        Log.d(TAG, "Loading mask...");

        int[] mask = MASKS[maskNumber];

        if (isMaskTexture1Created[0] > 0) {
            GLES11.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 1);
        }
        if (isMaskTexture2Created[0] > 0) {
            GLES11.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 2);
        }

        isMaskTexture1Created[0] = 0;
        isMaskTexture2Created[0] = 0;

        InputStream stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[0]);
        int res = MR.LoadMaskCoordsFromStream(stream, maskCoords);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (res != FSDK.FSDKE_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading mask coords from stream: " + res);
            GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
            return;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapDecodingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapDecodingOptions.inScaled = false; // to load original image without scaling

        FSDK.HImage img1 = new FSDK.HImage();
        if (mask[1] == -1) { // if no image
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img1);
        } else {
            stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[1]);
            byte[] data = null;
            try {
                data = readBytes(stream);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (data != null) {
                res = FSDK.LoadImageFromPngBufferWithAlpha(img1, data, data.length);
                Log.d(TAG, "Load mask image of size " + data.length + " with result " + res);
                int[] w = new int[]{0};
                int[] h = new int[]{0};
                FSDK.GetImageWidth(img1, w);
                FSDK.GetImageHeight(img1, h);
                Log.d(TAG, "Mask image size: " + w[0] + " x " + h[0]);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error loading mask image, using empty image");
                FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img1);
            }
        }

        FSDK.HImage img2 = new FSDK.HImage();
        if (mask[2] == -1) { // if no normal image
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img2);
        } else {
            stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[2]);
            byte[] data = null;
            try {
                data = readBytes(stream);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (data != null) {
                res = FSDK.LoadImageFromPngBufferWithAlpha(img2, data, data.length);
                Log.d(TAG, "Load mask normal image of size " + data.length + " with result " + res);
                int[] w = new int[]{0};
                int[] h = new int[]{0};
                FSDK.GetImageWidth(img2, w);
                FSDK.GetImageHeight(img2, h);
                Log.d(TAG, "Mask normal image size: " + w[0] + " x " + h[0]);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error loading mask normal image, using empty image");
                FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img2);
            }
        }

        res = MR.LoadMask(img1, img2, textures[1], textures[2], isMaskTexture1Created, isMaskTexture2Created);
        FSDK.FreeImage(img1);
        FSDK.FreeImage(img2);

        Log.d(TAG, "Mask loaded with result " + res + " texture1Created:" + isMaskTexture1Created[0] + " texture2Created:" + isMaskTexture2Created[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, "Mask textures: " + textures[1] + " " + textures[2]);

        GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) { //call opengl functions only inside these functions!
        GLES11.glClear(GLES11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (!isResized) {
            return;
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            if (updateSurfaceTexture) {
                surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
                updateSurfaceTexture = false;
            }
        }

        if (isMaskChanged) {
            maskLoaded = mask;
            loadMask(mask);
            isMaskChanged = false;
        }

        int rotation = 1;

        // First, drawing without mask to get image buffer
        int res = MR.DrawGLScene(textures[0], 0, trackingFeatures, rotation, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO, textures[1], textures[2], maskCoords, 0, 0, width, height);
        if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in the first MR.DrawGLScene call: " + res);
        }
        GLES11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES11.GL_RGBA, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

        face_count[0] = 0;

        processCameraImage();

        // Second, drawing with mask atop of image
        res = MR.DrawGLScene(textures[0], (int) face_count[0], trackingFeatures, rotation, MASKS[maskLoaded][3], textures[1], textures[2], maskCoords, isMaskTexture1Created[0], isMaskTexture2Created[0], width, height);
        if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in the second MR.DrawGLScene call: " + res);
        }

        // Save snapshot if needed
        if (isTakingSnapshot.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            GLES11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES11.GL_RGBA, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
            snapshotImageMode.mode = FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;
            res = FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(snapshotImage, pixelBuffer.array(), width, height, width * 4, snapshotImageMode);
            if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error loading snapshot image to FaceSDK: " + res);
            } else {
                FSDK.MirrorImage(snapshotImage, false);

                String galleryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
                final String filename = galleryPath + "/MirrorRealityDemo" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                res = FSDK.SaveImageToFile(snapshotImage, filename);
                Log.d(TAG, "saving snapshot to " + filename);

                FSDK.FreeImage(snapshotImage);

                if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK == res) {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                            File f = new File(filename);
                            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                            mainActivity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        // Show fps
        ++frameCount;
        long timeCurrent = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (startTime == 0) startTime = timeCurrent;
        long diff = timeCurrent - startTime;
        if (diff >= 3000) {
            final float fps = frameCount / (diff / 1000.0f);
            frameCount = 0;
            startTime = 0;

            final TextView fpsTextView = mainActivity.fpsTextView();
            mainActivity.fpsTextView().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!mainActivity.isFinishing()) {
                        fpsTextView.setText(fps + " FPS");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void processCameraImage() {
        //clear previous features
        for (int i = 0; i < MR.MAX_FACES; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = 0;
                trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = 0;
            }
        }

        cameraImageMode.mode = FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;
        int res = FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(cameraImage, pixelBuffer.array(), width, height, width * 4, cameraImageMode);
        if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading camera image to FaceSDK: " + res);
            return;
        }

        FSDK.MirrorImage(cameraImage, false);
        int[] widthByReference = new int[1];
        int[] heightByReference = new int[1];
        FSDK.GetImageWidth(cameraImage, widthByReference);
        FSDK.GetImageHeight(cameraImage, heightByReference);
        int width = widthByReference[0];
        int height = heightByReference[0];

        int rotation = 0;
        if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_PORTRAIT) {
            rotation = 2;
        } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            rotation = 3;
        } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_LANDSCAPE) {
            rotation = 1;
        }

        if (rotation > 0) {
            FSDK.HImage rotated = new FSDK.HImage();
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(rotated);
            FSDK.RotateImage90(cameraImage, rotation, rotated);
            FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, rotated, face_count, IDs);
            FSDK.FreeImage(rotated);
        } else {
            FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, cameraImage, face_count, IDs);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) face_count[0]; ++i) {
            FSDK.GetTrackerFacialFeatures(tracker, 0, IDs[i], trackingFeatures[i]);
            if (rotation > 0) {
                if (rotation == 1) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                        int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - x;
                    }
                } else if (rotation == 2) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                        int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = x;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        FSDK.FreeImage(cameraImage);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) { //call opengl functions only inside these functions!
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        if (!isResizeCalled) {
            isResizeCalled = true;
            mainView.resizeForPerformance(width, height);
            return;
        }

        GLES11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> psize = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        if (psize.size() > 0) {
            int i = 0;
            int optDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Log.d(TAG, "Choosing preview resolution closer to " + width + " x " + height);

            double neededScale = height / (double) width;
            for (int j = 0; j < psize.size(); ++j) {
                double scale = psize.get(j).width / (double) psize.get(j).height;
                int distance = (int) (10000 * Math.abs(scale - neededScale));

                Log.d(TAG, "Choosing preview resolution, probing " + psize.get(j).width + " x " + psize.get(j).height + " distance: " + distance);
                if (distance < optDistance) {
                    i = j;
                    optDistance = distance;
                } else if (distance == optDistance) {
                    // try to avoid too low resolution
                    if ((psize.get(i).width < 300 || psize.get(i).height < 300)
                            && psize.get(j).width > psize.get(i).width && psize.get(j).height > psize.get(i).height) {
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Using optimal preview size: " + psize.get(i).width + " x " + psize.get(i).height);
            param.setPreviewSize(psize.get(i).width, psize.get(i).height);

            // adjusting viewport to camera aspect ratio
            int viewportHeight = (int) (width * (psize.get(i).width * 1.0f / psize.get(i).height));

            GLES11.glViewport(0, 0, width, viewportHeight);

            this.width = width;
            this.height = viewportHeight;
            pixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.width * this.height * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        }

        param.set("orientation", "landscape");
        camera.setParameters(param);
        camera.startPreview();
        inPreview = true;
        isResized = true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    private void initTex() {
        textures = new int[3];
        GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
        GLES11.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GLES11.glGenTextures(3, textures, 0);
        GLES11.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES11.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES11.GL_NEAREST);
    }

    private void deleteTex() {
        GLES11.glDeleteTextures(3, textures, 0);
    }

    public synchronized void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture st) {
        updateSurfaceTexture = true;
        mainView.requestRender();
    }

    public synchronized void snapshot() {
        isTakingSnapshot.set(true);
    }
}
```

Any type of help is appreciated ... thank you so much

[here is the preview that i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhcsQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried making sense, but there is few knowledge on what API Level your trying to target , that may also be the problem or maybe the problem may be the Test Device.

But lets rewrite the camera Display code:

1)

```
 public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(android.hardware.Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo camInfo =
                    new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(getBackFacingCameraId(), camInfo);


            Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            int rotation = display.getRotation();
            int degrees = 0;
            switch (rotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    degrees = 0;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    degrees = 90;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    degrees = 180;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    degrees = 270;
                    break;
            }

            int result;
            if (camInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                result = (camInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
            } else {  // back-facing
                result = (camInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
        }
```

Call setCameraDisplayOrientation() method in surfaceCreated callback as the following:

```
 @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) { 
        camera = Camera.open();
        setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity(), CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
    }
```

Method 2 is to try:

Get the phone's orientation by using a sensor and this makes life much easier because the orientation will be properly handle

You can find more about this within this link: [Is Android's CameraInfo.orientation correctly documented? Incorrectly implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055460/is-androids-camerainfo-orientation-correctly-documented-incorrectly-implemente/9095288#9095288)

Method 3:

edit your code like

```
public class MainRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
    public static final String TAG = "MainRenderer";

    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 0;
    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_PORTRAIT = 1;
    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2;
    public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_LANDSCAPE = 3;
    private Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo;
    public volatile int deviceOrientation = DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    private FSDK.HTracker tracker;

    private int[] textures;

    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
    private boolean updateSurfaceTexture = false;

    private FSDK.FSDK_Features[] trackingFeatures;
    private MR.MaskFeatures maskCoords;
    private int[] isMaskTexture1Created = new int[]{0};
    private int[] isMaskTexture2Created = new int[]{0};

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private ByteBuffer pixelBuffer;

    private FSDK.HImage cameraImage = new FSDK.HImage();
    private FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE cameraImageMode = new FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE();
    private FSDK.HImage snapshotImage = new FSDK.HImage();
    private FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE snapshotImageMode = new FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE();

    private MainView mainView;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    private volatile boolean isResizeCalled = false;
    private volatile boolean isResized = false;

    public long IDs[] = new long[MR.MAX_FACES];
    public long face_count[] = new long[1];

    private long frameCount = 0;
    private long startTime = 0;

    private AtomicBoolean isTakingSnapshot = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static final int[][] MASKS = new int[][]{
            {R.raw.lips_pink, R.drawable.lips_pink, R.drawable.lips_pink_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
            {R.raw.lips_purple, R.drawable.lips_purple, R.drawable.lips_purple_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
            {R.raw.lips_red, R.drawable.lips_red, R.drawable.lips_red_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
    };

    private int mask = 0;
    private int maskLoaded = 0;
    private volatile boolean isMaskChanged = false;
    private boolean inPreview = false;

    public void changeMask(int i) {
        mask += i;
        isMaskChanged = true;
    }

    public MainRenderer(MainView view) {
        tracker = Application.tracker;

        mainView = view;
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) mainView.getContext();

        trackingFeatures = new FSDK.FSDK_Features[MR.MAX_FACES];
        for (int i = 0; i < MR.MAX_FACES; ++i) {
            trackingFeatures[i] = new FSDK.FSDK_Features();
            for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                trackingFeatures[i].features[j] = new FSDK.TPoint();
            }
        }
        maskCoords = new MR.MaskFeatures();
    }

    public void close() {
        updateSurfaceTexture = false;
        surfaceTexture.release();
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        deleteTex();
    }

    public void startCamera() {
        if (inPreview) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            inPreview = false;
        }
        //NB: if you don't release the current camera before switching, you app will crash
        camera.release();

            //swap the id of the camera to be used
    //Below i have tried to change the camera facing
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraInfo.facing = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
            } else {
                cameraInfo.facing = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
            }
            camera = Camera.open(cameraInfo.facing);
            //Code snippet for this method from somewhere on android developers, i forget where
            //setCameraDisplayOrientation(mainActivity, cameraInfo.facing, camera);
            try {
                //this step is critical or preview on new camera will no know where to render to
                camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            camera.startPreview();
            inPreview = true;
        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) { //call opengl functions only inside these functions!
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
            isResizeCalled = false;
            isResized = false;

            initTex();
            loadMask(mask);

            surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textures[0]);
            surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

            // Find the ID of the camera
            int cameraId = 0;
            boolean frontCameraFound = false;
            cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                }
                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    cameraId = i;
                    frontCameraFound = true;
                }
            }

            if (frontCameraFound) {
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
            } else {
                camera = Camera.open();
            }

            try {
                camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            GLES11.glClearColor

(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //background color
    }

    private byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 16384;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }

    // must be called from the thread with OpenGL context!
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    public void loadMask(int maskNumber) {
        GLES11.glDisable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);

        Log.d(TAG, "Loading mask...");

        int[] mask = MASKS[maskNumber];

        if (isMaskTexture1Created[0] > 0) {
            GLES11.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 1);
        }
        if (isMaskTexture2Created[0] > 0) {
            GLES11.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 2);
        }

        isMaskTexture1Created[0] = 0;
        isMaskTexture2Created[0] = 0;

        InputStream stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[0]);
        int res = MR.LoadMaskCoordsFromStream(stream, maskCoords);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (res != FSDK.FSDKE_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading mask coords from stream: " + res);
            GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
            return;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapDecodingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapDecodingOptions.inScaled = false; // to load original image without scaling

        FSDK.HImage img1 = new FSDK.HImage();
        if (mask[1] == -1) { // if no image
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img1);
        } else {
            stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[1]);
            byte[] data = null;
            try {
                data = readBytes(stream);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (data != null) {
                res = FSDK.LoadImageFromPngBufferWithAlpha(img1, data, data.length);
                Log.d(TAG, "Load mask image of size " + data.length + " with result " + res);
                int[] w = new int[]{0};
                int[] h = new int[]{0};
                FSDK.GetImageWidth(img1, w);
                FSDK.GetImageHeight(img1, h);
                Log.d(TAG, "Mask image size: " + w[0] + " x " + h[0]);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error loading mask image, using empty image");
                FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img1);
            }
        }

        FSDK.HImage img2 = new FSDK.HImage();
        if (mask[2] == -1) { // if no normal image
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img2);
        } else {
            stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[2]);
            byte[] data = null;
            try {
                data = readBytes(stream);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (data != null) {
                res = FSDK.LoadImageFromPngBufferWithAlpha(img2, data, data.length);
                Log.d(TAG, "Load mask normal image of size " + data.length + " with result " + res);
                int[] w = new int[]{0};
                int[] h = new int[]{0};
                FSDK.GetImageWidth(img2, w);
                FSDK.GetImageHeight(img2, h);
                Log.d(TAG, "Mask normal image size: " + w[0] + " x " + h[0]);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error loading mask normal image, using empty image");
                FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img2);
            }
        }

        res = MR.LoadMask(img1, img2, textures[1], textures[2], isMaskTexture1Created, isMaskTexture2Created);
        FSDK.FreeImage(img1);
        FSDK.FreeImage(img2);

        Log.d(TAG, "Mask loaded with result " + res + " texture1Created:" + isMaskTexture1Created[0] + " texture2Created:" + isMaskTexture2Created[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, "Mask textures: " + textures[1] + " " + textures[2]);

        GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) { //call opengl functions only inside these functions!
        GLES11.glClear(GLES11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (!isResized) {
            return;
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            if (updateSurfaceTexture) {
                surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
                updateSurfaceTexture = false;
            }
        }

        if (isMaskChanged) {
            maskLoaded = mask;
            loadMask(mask);
            isMaskChanged = false;
        }

        int rotation = 1;

        // First, drawing without mask to get image buffer
        int res = MR.DrawGLScene(textures[0], 0, trackingFeatures, rotation, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO, textures[1], textures[2], maskCoords, 0, 0, width, height);
        if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in the first MR.DrawGLScene call: " + res);
        }
        GLES11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES11.GL_RGBA, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

        face_count[0] = 0;

        processCameraImage();

        // Second, drawing with mask atop of image
        res = MR.DrawGLScene(textures[0], (int) face_count[0], trackingFeatures, rotation, MASKS[maskLoaded][3], textures[1], textures[2], maskCoords, isMaskTexture1Created[0], isMaskTexture2Created[0], width, height);
        if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in the second MR.DrawGLScene call: " + res);
        }

        // Save snapshot if needed
        if (isTakingSnapshot.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            GLES11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES11.GL_RGBA, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
            snapshotImageMode.mode = FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;
            res = FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(snapshotImage, pixelBuffer.array(), width, height, width * 4, snapshotImageMode);
            if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error loading snapshot image to FaceSDK: " + res);
            } else {
                FSDK.MirrorImage(snapshotImage, false);

                String galleryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
                final String filename = galleryPath + "/MirrorRealityDemo" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                res = FSDK.SaveImageToFile(snapshotImage, filename);
                Log.d(TAG, "saving snapshot to " + filename);

                FSDK.FreeImage(snapshotImage);

                if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK == res) {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                            File f = new File(filename);
                            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                            mainActivity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        // Show fps
        ++frameCount;
        long timeCurrent = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (startTime == 0) startTime = timeCurrent;
        long diff = timeCurrent - startTime;
        if (diff >= 3000) {
            final float fps = frameCount / (diff / 1000.0f);
            frameCount = 0;
            startTime = 0;

            final TextView fpsTextView = mainActivity.fpsTextView();
            mainActivity.fpsTextView().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!mainActivity.isFinishing()) {
                        fpsTextView.setText(fps + " FPS");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void processCameraImage() {
        //clear previous features
        for (int i = 0; i < MR.MAX_FACES; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = 0;
                trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = 0;
            }
        }

        cameraImageMode.mode = FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;
        int res = FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(cameraImage, pixelBuffer.array(), width, height, width * 4, cameraImageMode);
        if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading camera image to FaceSDK: " + res);
            return;
        }

        FSDK.MirrorImage(cameraImage, false);
        int[] widthByReference = new int[1];
        int[] heightByReference = new int[1];
        FSDK.GetImageWidth(cameraImage, widthByReference);
        FSDK.GetImageHeight(cameraImage, heightByReference);
        int width = widthByReference[0];
        int height = heightByReference[0];

        int rotation = 0;
        if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_PORTRAIT) {
            rotation = 2;
        } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            rotation = 3;
        } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_LANDSCAPE) {
            rotation = 1;
        }

        if (rotation > 0) {
            FSDK.HImage rotated = new FSDK.HImage();
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(rotated);
            FSDK.RotateImage90(cameraImage, rotation, rotated);
            FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, rotated, face_count, IDs);
            FSDK.FreeImage(rotated);
        } else {
            FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, cameraImage, face_count, IDs);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) face_count[0]; ++i) {
            FSDK.GetTrackerFacialFeatures(tracker, 0, IDs[i], trackingFeatures[i]);
            if (rotation > 0) {
                if (rotation == 1) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                        int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - x;
                    }
                } else if (rotation == 2) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                        int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                        trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = x;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        FSDK.FreeImage(cameraImage);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) { //call opengl functions only inside these functions!
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        if (!isResizeCalled) {
            isResizeCalled = true;
            mainView.resizeForPerformance(width, height);
            return;
        }

        GLES11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> psize = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        if (psize.size() > 0) {
            int i = 0;
            int optDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Log.d(TAG, "Choosing preview resolution closer to " + width + " x " + height);

            double neededScale = height / (double) width;
            for (int j = 0; j < psize.size(); ++j) {
                double scale = psize.get(j).width / (double) psize.get(j).height;
                int distance = (int) (10000 * Math.abs(scale - neededScale));

                Log.d(TAG, "Choosing preview resolution, probing " + psize.get(j).width + " x " + psize.get(j).height + " distance: " + distance);
                if (distance < optDistance) {
                    i = j;
                    optDistance = distance;
                } else if (distance == optDistance) {
                    // try to avoid too low resolution
                    if ((psize.get(i).width < 300 || psize.get(i).height < 300)
                            && psize.get(j).width > psize.get(i).width && psize.get(j).height > psize.get(i).height) {
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Using optimal preview size: " + psize.get(i).width + " x " + psize.get(i).height);
            param.setPreviewSize(psize.get(i).width, psize.get(i).height);

            // adjusting viewport to camera aspect ratio
            int viewportHeight = (int) (width * (psize.get(i).width * 1.0f / psize.get(i).height));

            GLES11.glViewport(0, 0, width, viewportHeight);

            this.width = width;
            this.height = viewportHeight;
            pixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.width * this.height * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        }

        param.set("orientation", "landscape");
        camera.setParameters(param);
        camera.startPreview();
        inPreview = true;
        isResized = true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    private void initTex() {
        textures = new int[3];
        GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
        GLES11.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GLES11.glGenTextures(3, textures, 0);
        GLES11.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES11.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES11.GL_NEAREST);
    }

    private void deleteTex() {
        GLES11.glDeleteTextures(3, textures, 0);
    }

    public synchronized void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture st) {
        updateSurfaceTexture = true;
        mainView.requestRender();
    }

    public synchronized void snapshot() {
        isTakingSnapshot.set(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your efforts to help me!

Comment: No problem..did any of the method above help??

Comment: Yes i don't know about the third because i havenn't tried but  the second one is the one i implemented and that was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes due to android not knowing what orientation is the previous activity coming from, try setting the orientation of the application with

```
     android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

or try the following:

Add the orientation attribute in the manifest

```
 android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
                                     "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```

So in your case it will be

```
<activity android:name=".yourCameractivity"
      ....
      android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... but i've tried with the android:screenOrientation="nosensor" and the preview of the front camera is in portrait and the preview of the rear is still in reverse portrait @Lucien

Comment: how about android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" ?

Comment: No it doesn't, the review of the rear camera is still oriented inverse portrait... maybe i've written something in the code... have you looked the code?

Comment: So have you found anything?