# Android - Camera

Tags: android

Can someone provide me some code sample about capturing a "full" image from a camera and then converting it in "startActivityForResult" as a byte, and also as a bitmap to display in imageView. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 2):

You've probably seen this but.  There's a great tutorial here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

For Bitmaps
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

I actually have an app that does that, I can send it to you later when I get home from work.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky dealing with the camera. Here is a piece of code that I had written for an app.

```
private final int RECEIVE_CAMERA_PICTURE = 10;
private Uri mCameraUri = null;

mCameraUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCameraUri);
mtimeCameraAcessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RECEIVE_CAMERA_PICTURE);
```

Now to process the image capture, the following should be placed in the onActivityResult() method. You will notice that I have put in a check to fetch the orientation of the image being captured. This value will be helpful in displaying the image via an ImageView in a different activity:

```
int orientation = -10;

Intent displayCameraPictureIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilterActivity.class);
displayCameraPictureIntent.setData(mCameraUri);

String filePath = OtherUtils.getRealPathFromURI(mContext, mCameraUri);
long fileSize = new File(filePath).length();

Cursor mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION, MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE }, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + ">=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(mtimeCameraAcessed/1000 - 1)}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " desc");

//ensure that the app doesn't consume inappropriate data
if (mediaCursor != null && mtimeCameraAcessed != 0 && mediaCursor.getCount() != 0 ) {
    while(mediaCursor.moveToNext()){
         long size = mediaCursor.getLong(1);
         //Extra check to make sure that we are getting the orientation from the proper file
         if(size == fileSize){
               orientation = mediaCursor.getInt(0);
               break;
         }
    }
}


displayCameraPictureIntent.putExtra("orientationValue", orientation);
startActivity(displayCameraPictureIntent);
```

Now, to display the image, inside a new activity:

```
private Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
shareImageUri = imageUri;
try {
imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
} catch (Exception e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block         
} 

// check whether image is in landscape or portrait mode
if(getIntent().getIntExtra("orientationValue", 1) == 90) { 
     //image is in portrait. So, rotate the image by 90degrees so that it is displayed in portrait mode
}

//now, set the bitmap to the appropriate imageView. You might want to scale the bitmap, to avoid
//memory issues.
```

You would also want to check this link, which explains the orientation aspect of this piece of code:
[Images taken with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE always returns 1 for ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION on some newer devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450539/images-taken-with-action-image-capture-always-returns-1-for-exifinterface-tag-or/8864367#8864367)

Please let me know, if you have any further questions or concerns. If instead, you want to use the Camera api, I forewarn you that it is a mighty challenging task, but definitely plausible.