# Android Image Preview from gallery / camera different

Tags: java, android

I use two buttons:
btnShoot = to take a photo with the camera api
btnGallery = to select a photo from the gallery

Later, it will be possible to upload the saved img.

The following PhotoIntentActivity.java I use for the camera app and preview the image (imageView1). The problem is now, the image will displayed rotated -90° in portrait-Mode (Preview and saved Image on Gallery).

```
package com.lo.android.photo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.lo.android.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.database.Cursor;



public class PhotoIntentActivity extends Activity {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;

    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

    private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;


    /* Photo album for this application */
    private String getAlbumName() {
        return getString(R.string.album_name);
    }

    /* Photo directory for this application */
    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

            storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (! storageDir.exists()){
                        Log.d("lo", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return storageDir;
    }

    /* Photo file name for this application */
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    public Bitmap setPic() {

        int orientation;

        try {
            if (mCurrentPhotoPath == null) {
                return null;
            }

        /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
        /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */
        /* Get the size of the ImageView */

        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        /* Get the size of the image */
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
        int scaleFactor = 1;
        if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
            scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
        }

        /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mCurrentPhotoPath);

        orientation = exif
                .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

        Log.e("ExifInteface .........", "rotation ="+orientation);

//      exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, 90);

        Log.e("orientation", "" + orientation);
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
            m.postRotate(180);
//          m.postScale((float) bm.getWidth(), (float) bm.getHeight());
            // if(m.preRotate(90)){
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
            return bitmap;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            m.postRotate(90); 
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
            return bitmap;
        }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            m.postRotate(270);
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
            return bitmap;
        } 

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return mImageBitmap;
    }


    private void galleryAddPic() {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
            File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        switch(actionCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
            File f = null;

            try {
                f = setUpPhotoFile();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                f = null;
                mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;          
        } // switch

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }

    private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            setPic();
            galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }

    }

    Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener = 
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
        }
    };


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        mImageBitmap = null;

        /// gallery picture path ///


        Button picBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShoot);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
                picBtn, 
                mTakePicOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
        );

        Button btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);
        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });







        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        } else {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                handleBigCameraPhoto();
            }
            break;
        } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B
        }
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                cursor.close();
            }

        }// switch

    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);
        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );
    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
     * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
     * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
     * found, this method returns false.
     * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
     *
     * @param context The application's environment.
     * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
     *
     * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
     *         responded to, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
            Button btn, 
            Button.OnClickListener onClickListener,
            String intentName
    ) {
        if (isIntentAvailable(this, intentName)) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);            
        } else {
            btn.setText( 
                getText(R.string.cannot).toString() + " " + btn.getText());
            btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

}
```

How can use only one preview with the correct rotation in portrait-mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852154/android-camera-unexplainable-rotation-on-capture-for-some-devices-not-in-exif

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
File photos = new File(selectedImagePath);
                ExifInterface exif = null;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(photos.getPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                int angle = 0;

                if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                    angle = 90;
                } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                    angle = 180;
                } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                    angle = 270;
                }
                Bitmap b;
                Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                mat.postRotate(angle);

                b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                        bm.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

then set this "b" bitmap wherever you want to set.

Comment: @user1735856 Let me know whether this helps you or not and if helps you please accept it as answer.

Comment: I will do, thank you. Actually I fail to include your code in my code above edited:-(

Comment: as a rookie, i´ve tried a lot to include it - but everything fails. Is there any example out the to see it in action?

Comment: @user1735856 Check answer of this question. I hope this will help you in integrating. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430895/capture-photo-rotate-90-degree-in-samsung-mobile

Comment: I´ve tried it now (With Exif). See above edited code. I get no exception, but the effect is the same: The preview display the image only -90° in landscape-Mode. The Gallery also do this.

Comment: the log display a warn: "rotation = 0" and orientation "0" so it seems, the exif-part doesn´t work correctly