# video orientation changed after upload to server android

Tags: android, orientation, video-capture

I am creating app where I need to upload Images and Videos which is taken by Default camera of device. Whenever I upload Image or Video orientation got changed to landscape. 
I have solved this issue using this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430895/capture-photo-rotate-90-degree-in-samsung-mobile). Now I want to do the same for Video. Is it possible to change orientation after video captured. Any third party library?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue? My friend is facing same issue.

Comment: please drop your video capturing code so user can get idea where is problem