# Unable to get orientation when uploading image from library

Tags: android, image, android-orientation

I'm unable to get the orientation when selecting an image from my library. If I go to image details, I can see the image orientation is set to 90 degrees. However, my orientation is always 0.

```
String[] orientationColumn =  { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
Cursor cur = managedQuery(data.getData(), orientationColumn, null, null, null);
int orientation = -1;

if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
     orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
}
```

Using ExitInterface:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(data.getData().getPath());
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

Both ways return 0. I launch the select from library activity like so:

```
protected void selectFromLibrary() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,
            REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE_FILE);
}
```

This is on an LG G2 running 4.4.2

Comment: the exif data in your mobile might be in another format not recognized by exifInterface. It happens occasionally

Comment: What does that mean? I'm out of luck?

Comment: try opening the image in a notepad and search for any human readable sentences you will know what I mean.Hint: Exif data look like xml tags

Answer (score 5):

I've come across couple of solutions (like here [Images taken with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE always returns 1 for ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION on some newer devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450539/images-taken-with-action-image-capture-always-returns-1-for-exifinterface-tag-or)), but none of them where working for me.

What finally saved me was this piece of code:
http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/packages/apps/Gallery2/src/com/android/gallery3d/data/Exif.java

So, at the beginning I am trying to get orientation using default exif methods. When it fails, I am releasing the beast.
My full code:

```
protected Matrix getRotationMatrix(String path, String mimeType, Context ctx, Uri imgUri)
{
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    try {

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);

        if (mimeType.contains("jpeg") && exif != null) {
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            if (orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                        mtx.setScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        mtx.setRotate(180);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                        mtx.setRotate(180);
                        mtx.postScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                        mtx.setRotate(90);
                        mtx.postScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        mtx.setRotate(90);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                        mtx.setRotate(-90);
                        mtx.postScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        mtx.setRotate(-90);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ctx != null && imgUri != null)
                {
                    Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(imgUri,
                            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION},
                            null, null, null);

                    try {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
                            if (orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)
                                mtx.postRotate(cursor.getInt(0));
                            else {
                                // last try...
                                mtx.postRotate( Exif.getOrientation(ctx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri)));
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return mtx;
    }

    return mtx;
}
```

Then I use this matrix inside `Bitmap.createBitmap` method to get image rotated in right way.

Comment: Exif.java file returns exact true values. This solved my problems with all samsungs. Thanks man.