# Android: Get App-Name from Intent

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm currently working on a multi image picker control. I'm using this [Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image) solution for generating a list of possible intents from which the user picks one.

As seen here:

```
List<ResolveInfo> listGall = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(gallIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listGall) {
    final Intent finalIntent = new Intent(gallIntent);
    finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,     res.activityInfo.name));
yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
}
```

But all names I can resolve by ResolveInfo and its properties are not user friendly labels. So I'm looking for way to get the launcher name for the given activities.

Comment: https://github.com/rahulr4/MultiImagePickerCropper2 Try this for reference

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `loadLabel()` on the `ResolveInfo` to get a "user friendly label". [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) that demonstrates this.

Comment: Cool! Works, thank you! ResolveInfo also contains loadIcon so when you use a custom dialog (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) you're able to build a dialog with the launcher names and the icons.