# How to retrieve the application name that launched a share intent to my application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an application that can receive data (image or text) as a share intent. So from any application, if you want to share a text or an image, my application will be in the list.

I would like to know if there is a way (in my bound activity) to know which application started it ?

Comment: is this what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/5938014/6689101

Comment: You can use getIntent().getPackage().

Comment: Have you tried [getCallingActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()) or [getCallingPackage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingPackage())

Comment: @SahilMunjal Thank you, I'll give it a test

Comment: None of these solutions is working, it always returns null.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Currently android doesn't support to detect the package name(of application) of intent who sent it. Intent doesn't contain the sender information.*

*getCallingActivity() or getCallingPackage() will only work when the sender what to return something from you app. Like photo capture or cropping app*

Comment: I wasn't asking for a solution to implement my activity as a share intent receiver. Sorry if that was unclear. I'm trying to know which application started my application with a share intent.