# Choose an image from camera or gallery

Tags: java, android, media

How can I offer the user the option of choosing an  image from the camera or gallery and retrieve the Resource id associated?

Comment: Take a look to this answer with an intent that merges both requests (Camera & Gallery) in a unique Intent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32475805/2232889

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this as an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Here is how you retreive the returned image.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

switch(requestCode) { 
case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    }
}
}
```

(code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2508138)

Comment: Also you can get more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I dont need the Bitmap at this moment, I'm handling an int[] with the app's image resources and I want to add the image selected by the user

Comment: The code i give you allows you to add the image selected by the user.

Comment: this code only picks images from gallery, and does not give the user an option to capture an image from the camera like the original question suggested.