# Dialog to pick image from gallery or from camera

Tags: android

Is there a standard way to call dialog box with choose either to pick an image from the camera or to get from gallery (like in build-in phone book or Skype)?

I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498259/choose-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery) but the code opens gallery without suggesting to pick it from camera.

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab
Android: 2.3.3

Comment: Take a look to this answer with an intent that merges both requests (Camera & Gallery) in a unique Intent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32475805/2232889

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The code below can be used for taking a photo and for picking a photo. Just show a dialog with two options and upon selection, use the appropriate code.

To take picture from camera:

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code (called requestCode)
```

To pick photo from gallery:

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//one can be replaced with any action code
```

`onActivityResult` code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            imageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }

    break; 
    case 1:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            imageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

Finally add this permission in the manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: There is no need for the Camera permissions because it opens the default app.

Comment: We can create common chooser for camera and gallery both same as like WHATS APP EDIT PROFILE .. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825289/i-want-to-make-a-dialog-screen-like-whatsapp-profile-photo-dialog-screen ... but the problem is occurred at onActivityResult() ..we can't make able to differentiate between Whether we choose image from gallery Or We captured image from Camera? so how can we make differentiate between them at onActivityResult()? Any Solutions? plz Help me if you have!!

Comment: @tasomaniac "There is no need for the Camera permissions because it opens the default app." – This is not true anymore. Starting a camera intent without android.permission.CAMERA will result in a SecurityException and probably crash your app as of Android 6 (5?).

Comment: @Jeremy No that's wrong. If you don't have the permission at all, you can just use it. Because it is not your app opening the camera. 
The nuance is that if you have the permission and if the user rejected the permission, then using this `Intent` as a fallback throws SecurityException. 
More info: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/e9kyM7VXajz

Comment: Camera permission is now needed to open camera intent @tasomaniac

Comment: @SaadBilal I just put a link from a Google+ post that says it is not needed. Please provide a link or a source backing your argument. I have an app that opens camera intent without permission.

Comment: with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE i receive imageReturnedIntent.getData() == null why?

Comment: According to official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics taking photo doesn't save image in Uri returned from intents getData(). You can only get thumbnail from result intent (intent.getBundle().get("data)). Full size image can be written to file prepared for this purpose before startActivityForResult is called.

Comment: How to add both gallary and camera e.g "Complete action using gallery or camera app"

Comment: Here is a solution for the deprecation warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63654043/8462925

Answer (score 56):

I have merged some solutions to make a complete util for picking an image from Gallery or Camera. These are the features of [ImagePicker util gist](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2) (also in a [Github lib](https://github.com/Mariovc/ImagePicker)):

- Merged intents for Gallery and Camera resquests.
- Resize selected big images (e.g.: 2500 x 1600)
- Rotate image if necesary

**Screenshot:**

[image: ImagePicker starting intent]

**Edit**: Here is a fragment of code to get a merged Intent for Gallery and Camera apps together. 
You can see the full code at [ImagePicker util gist](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2) (also in a [Github lib](https://github.com/Mariovc/ImagePicker)):

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
    Intent chooserIntent = null;

    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_text));
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    }

    return chooserIntent;
}

private static List<Intent> addIntentsToList(Context context, List<Intent> list, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent targetedIntent = new Intent(intent);
        targetedIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        list.add(targetedIntent);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, Mario. Thank you so much! I tested it in a Samsung GT-I9100, a LG L7, but it fails when we try to put the image from camera in a Nexus 6 with Android 6. The solution would be adding this to your 58 line in ImagePicker.java: `boolean isCamera = (imageReturnedIntent == null || imageReturnedIntent.getData() == null);`

Comment: Thank you @GabrielMorenoIbarra . You fixed it, now it is in my code also.

Comment: what is `getTempFile` and how to use this function? please update the answer

Comment: It is a function to get a temporal File. Take a look to the link and you will find a more detailed script

Comment: Where in this would I put onActivityResult?

Comment: @ImagineThat on the activity you put the code for launching the Intent. Take a look to the [Github code](https://github.com/Mariovc/ImagePicker/blob/develop/sample/src/main/java/com/mvc/imagepicker/sample/MainActivity.java)

Comment: This was working, but I'm getting an error now: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app.id/cache/tempImage exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Comment: @Brainware, yes, it depends on Android version. Consider using `FileProvider` for API >= 23 and `Uri` for less.

Answer (score 19):

[This](https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage) library makes it simple.

Just Call:

```
PickImageDialog.on(MainActivity.this, new PickSetup(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
```

Then make your Activity implement IPickResult and override this below method.

```
@Override
public void onPickResult(PickResult r) {
    if (r.getError() == null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(r.getBitmap());

        //or

        imageView.setImageURI(r.getUri());
    } else {
        //Handle possible errors
        //TODO: do what you have to do with r.getError();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have amazon photos in my phone s7 edge when ever i select gallery option it redirect to amazon login page and in other phones its fine.. but i am testing in s7 edge

Comment: This is very messy approach, may affect whole code. Don't know why the guy created separate mvn repo.

Comment: Does this allow multi-select or multi-capture images?

Answer (score 14):

You can implement this code to select image from gallery or camera :-

```
private ImageView imageview;
private Button btnSelectImage;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private File destination = null;
private InputStream inputStreamImg;
private String imgPath = null;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA = 1, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY = 2;
```

Now on button click event, you can able to call your method of select Image. This is inside activity's onCreate.

```
imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
btnSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectImage);

//OnbtnSelectImage click event...
btnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
```

Outside of your activity's oncreate.

```
// Select image from camera and gallery
private void selectImage() {
    try {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        int hasPerm = pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, getPackageName());
        if (hasPerm == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose From Gallery","Cancel"};
            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("Select Option");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Choose From Gallery")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    inputStreamImg = null;
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA) {
        try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);

            Log.e("Activity", "Pick from Camera::>>> ");

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
                    getString(R.string.app_name), "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            imgPath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);
            Log.e("Activity", "Pick from Gallery::>>> ");

            imgPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
            destination = new File(imgPath.toString());
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Atlast, finally add the camera and write external storage permission to AndroidManifest.xml

It works for me greatly, hope it will also works for you.

Comment: I add camera permission but accure error and display "camera permission error"

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to get the image from gallery or capture the image and set it to the imageview in portrait mode then following code will help you..**

**In onCreate()**

```
imageViewRound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });




    private void selectImage() {
    Constants.iscamera = true;
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

     TextView title = new TextView(context);
     title.setText("Add Photo!");
        title.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        title.setPadding(10, 15, 15, 10);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        title.setTextSize(22);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            AddContactActivity.this);



    builder.setCustomTitle(title);

    // builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                // Intent intent = new
                // Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                /*
                 * File photo = new
                 * File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                 * "Pic.jpg"); intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                 * Uri.fromFile(photo)); imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                 */
                // startActivityForResult(intent,TAKE_PICTURE);

                Intent intents = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

                intents.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                // start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intents, TAKE_PICTURE);

            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}




    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_PICTURE:
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {


                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                            selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                    c.close();
                    imageViewRound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // Bitmap thumbnail =
                    // (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    Bitmap thumbnail = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                            picturePath, 500, 500);

                    // rotated
                    Bitmap thumbnail_r = imageOreintationValidator(
                            thumbnail, picturePath);
                    imageViewRound.setBackground(null);
                    imageViewRound.setImageBitmap(thumbnail_r);
                    IsImageSet = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            previewCapturedImage();

        }

        break;
    }

}



 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        // hide video preview

        imageViewRound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500,
                false);

        // rotated
        Bitmap thumbnail_r = imageOreintationValidator(resizedBitmap,
                fileUri.getPath());

        imageViewRound.setBackground(null);
        imageViewRound.setImageBitmap(thumbnail_r);
        IsImageSet = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}






    // for roted image......
private Bitmap imageOreintationValidator(Bitmap bitmap, String path) {

    ExifInterface ei;
    try {
        ei = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}



private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    try {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError err) {
        source.recycle();
        Date d = new Date();
        CharSequence s = DateFormat
                .format("MM-dd-yy-hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
        String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/RYB_pic/" + s.toString() + ".jpg";
        if ((fullPath != null) && (new File(fullPath).exists())) {
            new File(fullPath).delete();
        }
        bitmap = null;
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}




public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String pathToFile,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    Log.e("inSampleSize", "inSampleSize______________in storage"
            + options.inSampleSize);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile, options);
}




public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

    }

    return inSampleSize;
}




public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}






private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}






public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
```

**Hope This will help you....!!!**

If targetSdkVersion is higher than 24, then FileProvider is used to grant access.

Create an xml file(Path: res\xml) provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Add a Provider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

and replace

```
return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
```

To

```
               return FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", getOutputMediaFile(type));
```

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA deprecated update answer please.