# Strange path returned when selecting an image from the Android gallery

Tags: android

When I select an image from the gallery on my android device using the code in this thread:

[Dialog to pick image from gallery or from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera)

the path that is returned is like this "content://media/external/images/media/895", is that path correct? I can't seem to find it when browsing the phones directories in windows explorer and it doesn't seem to be directly referencing a JPEG image. I want to obtain a file path so I can make an imageView display this picture.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: its not the path its uri of the image..

Comment: What's the difference between the two?