# Dialog Screen Like WhatsApp Profile Photo Dialog Screen

Tags: android, android-intent

We can create common chooser for camera and gallery both same as like WHATS APP EDIT PROFILE .. [link][I want to make a Dialog Screen Like WhatsApp Profile Photo Dialog Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825289/i-want-to-make-a-dialog-screen-like-whatsapp-profile-photo-dialog-screen) ... but the problem is occurred at onActivityResult() ..we can't make able to differentiate between Whether we choose image from gallery Or We captured image from Camera? so how can we make differentiate between them at onActivityResult()? Any Solutions? plz Help me if you have!!