# Choose image from gallery or take from camera

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I have to make a button that will provide to choose image from gallery or take from camera.

```
 private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The result is working. If i choose from gallery, the imageviewer will view that, it also working if i choose taking photo from camera.
The problem is, in my showFileChooser() method, all of my intent are runing in same time, so when i choos from gallery, the camera still running also. I choose camera, the gallery is opening too. I think i should implement my code in switch case mode but i dont understand how to do that. Please kindly help to solve my beginner problem.

Comment: You should be asking the user where to choose the image from.

Comment: yes, thats my goal, but all of that two is running in same time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialog to pick image from gallery or from camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera)

Comment: Simple: Use a library like [this](https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage)

Answer (score 5):

Add a `alertDialog` and then in `onActivityResult` instead of case of 0 and 1 use the  `REQUEST_CAMERA` and `SELECT_FILE`. which you'll declare as in code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int SELECT_FILE = 2;

final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel"};
            android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                        PROFILE_PIC_COUNT = 1;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        PROFILE_PIC_COUNT = 1;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,SELECT_FILE);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        PROFILE_PIC_COUNT = 0;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }); 
            builder.show();
```

Comment: how to implement this inside my method called showFileChooser()?
I dont use direct implementation, but i used a button to call that method, then in my post is the method declaration

Comment: Just add this whole code in your showFileChooser() method . youll be good to go. This basically adds a alertdialog for user to choose between gallery and camera and then call startActivityForResult() accordingly.

Comment: Declatre these two lines globally though             private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int SELECT_FILE = 2;

Answer (score 1):

You should first decide like what action you want to perform like as follows

```
  public class PicModeSelectDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        private String[] picMode = {"Camera", "Gallery"};

        private IPicModeSelectListener iPicModeSelectListener;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setItems(picMode, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (iPicModeSelectListener != null)
                        iPicModeSelectListener.onPicModeSelected(Constants.PicModes.values()[which]);
                }
            });
            return builder.create();
        }

        public void setiPicModeSelectListener(IPicModeSelectListener iPicModeSelectListener) {
            this.iPicModeSelectListener = iPicModeSelectListener;
        }

        public interface IPicModeSelectListener {
            void onPicModeSelected(Constants.PicModes modes);
        }
    }
```

After that you can fire intent to open camera or gallery like follows:

```
if(openCamera){
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}else{
//open gallery
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*");
}
```

Comment: is this a class? but I implement my code in a method called showFileChooser()

Comment: Then you can also first open a dialog in showFileChooser() asking user for his action and then onItemClick() you can perform action accordingly.

Comment: would you illustrate your pattern plz

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a dialog with two buttons that will ask user to choose either `Gallery` or `Camera.`On Click of buttons set Intent for picking the images like below:

```
public void dialog()
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.cust_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Upload From");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_pop_up_gallery_camera);

        dialog.setTitle("Select an Option...");
        TextView txt_gallry=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_gallery);
        TextView txt_camera=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_camera);

        txt_gallry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            i.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(i, PHOTO_PICKER_ID);
            }
        });
        txt_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();



                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                File fil = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(fil));
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Here is the layout file for dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
              android:background="@color/lightpurple">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/galery_small"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView_gallery"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/camera"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView_camera"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so, i should make another activity outside my mainactivity?

Comment: No, Just put this code in you main activity and call this dialog on button click, where you were calling `showFileChooser() ` and also put that `xml` in your `res/layout` folder.

Comment: @BurhanuddinRabbani are you done with that? Or need help?