# Android Choose Image or Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-image, android-gallery

I have implemented the code for choosing an image from SD or Camera.
But, my image doesn't show up in `ImageView` and I can't choose an image from SD card.

When I click on an image from SD card it jumps instant back to my Activity.

```
    final String[] items = new String[] {"From Camera","From SD Card"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
            if(which == 0){
                intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"event_image"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"));
                imageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                try {
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageCaptureUri);
                    intent.putExtra("return data",true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.cancel();
            }else{
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"),PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    mImageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imagePicker = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_picker);
    imagePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String path ="";
    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
        imageCaptureUri = data.getData();
        path = getRealPathFromURI(imageCaptureUri);
        if(path == null)
            path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
        if(path != null){
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }
    }else{
        path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    }
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}


  public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI){
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentURI,proj,null,null,null);
    if(cursor == null) return null;
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialog to pick image from gallery or from camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera)

Comment: Simply use this library: https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to use permission **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** in AndroidManifest.xml
2. In your xml layout :

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/img"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="380dp"
       android:background="#f241c9" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:text="Take Photo" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnPick"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:text="Pick Photo" />
   ```
3. In your activity class :

   ```
   private static final String TAG = "my_log";
   private static final int REQUEST_CAPTURE_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
   private static final int REQUEST_PICK_FROM_FILE = 2;
   private static final int REQUEST_CROP_INTENT = 3;

   ImageView img;
   Button btnCapture, btnPick;
   File file;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
       btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
       btnPick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPick);

       btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
               file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "img_captured.jpg");
               // put Uri as extra in intent object
               intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
               startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_FROM_CAMERA);
           }
       });

       btnPick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setType("image/*");
               intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
               startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), REQUEST_PICK_FROM_FILE);
           }
       });

   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

       if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

       if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE_FROM_CAMERA) {
           try {
               cropImage(Uri.fromFile(file));
           } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Your device does not support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_FROM_FILE) {
           try {
               cropImage(data.getData());
           } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Your device does not support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CROP_INTENT) {
           // Create an instance of bundle and get the returned data
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           // get the cropped bitmap from extras
           Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
           img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           if (saveBitmapToStorage(bitmap)) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap saved to file successful.");
           } else {
               Log.d(TAG, "Failed to save Bitmap to storage.");
           }
       }

   }

   public void cropImage(Uri picUri) {
       //call the standard crop action intent
       Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
       //indicate image type and Uri of image
       cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
       //set crop properties
       cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
       //indicate aspect of desired crop
       cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
       cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
       //indicate output X and Y
       cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
       cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
       //retrieve data on return
       cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
       //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
       startActivityForResult(cropIntent, REQUEST_CROP_INTENT);
   }

   private boolean saveBitmapToStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
       boolean result = false;

       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "img_cropped.jpg");
       Log.d(TAG, "file path = " + file.getAbsolutePath());

       try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

           // send Broadcast to notify this photo and see it in Gallery
           Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
           Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
           mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
           sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

           result = true;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```