# How to take an image as an input from the user and view it in the database w/ Android Studio

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to create an app using Android Studio. My client wants to create an app for their online medicines website, wherein the user can take a photo of their prescription, the photo will be accessible by the admins and they can use that image to understand what does the user require and deliver those medications at the user's doorsteps.
So can anyone please guide me through with making this page, or maybe share a link where the making of such a page is shown? Would be really helpful, thank you for giving me your time.

Comment: First, how to take pictures: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics I recommend you take the approach under "Take a photo with a camera app".
Second: You will need some backend where you can upload the image. Do you already have it? Your backend will also need an "admin area" where admins can see the images (which most likely will be a website). If you need to provide this but don't know how, the simplest approach would probably be to start with Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexanderHoffmann . I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several possible approaches for this type of questions/requirements. I am mentioning a few steps to guide you through the process.

1. You will have to create a webserver, which will be storing the user data (profile, uploaded prescriptions, etc.). The user data (textual) will be stored in the Database, however, the images will be uploaded in a directory over the server, and their corresponding links will be stored in the DB for reference.
2. There will be a webserver API which will fetch user data (user unique ID) from app and then store it in the DB. The image part can be accepted in several ways: MultiPart, Base64 encoded, Byte Array Converted

   All these methods will send the image info from the android app to the webserver, which will follow the logic mentioned in Point 1 and save the image.
3. The Android app will have an activity where the user will either capture an image of the prescription form, using Camera, or can upload the image (if already captured/downloaded). You will have to learn doing this from similar links as these:

   - https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics
   - [Dialog to pick image from gallery or from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera)
4. The Android app will send the unique ID of the user, along with the image data, to the Webserver API, which in-turn process as per Point 2.

You can start implementing the process and then can turn up to StackOverflow again for guidance. There are numerous tutorials to implement a similar functionality too.

- https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/
- http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-upload-image-to-php-server/
- https://www.codepool.biz/take-a-photo-from-android-camera-and-upload-it-to-a-remote-php-server.html

All the best!