# Getting RuntimeException and NullPointerException when creating file for image taken with the camera

Tags: android, file, camera, gallery, photo

I am making a contact agenda app and I need to save the photos taken with the camer into the device gallery. I've been following this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics and looked and tried several fixes, but none seem to work.

Here is the error thrown after taking the picture:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.agendaandroid, PID: 4456
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.agendaandroid/com.example.agendaandroid.NuevaPersonaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.agendaandroid.NuevaPersonaActivity.onActivityResult(NuevaPersonaActivity.java:213)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

this is my NuevaPersonaActivity.java:

```
<pre>
package com.example.agendaandroid;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import clases.Contacto;
import clases.Correo;
import clases.Telefono;
import controlador.BaseDeDatos;

public class NuevaPersonaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Contacto contacto;
    private final int INTENT_GALERIA = 0;
    private final int INTENT_CAMARA = 1;
    private String direccionActualFoto;

    private String[] permisos = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nueva_persona);

    }

    public void btnAnadirContacto(View view) {
        //TODO Controlar de manera más efectiva que el input no esté vacío
        //TODO sacar foto con la cámara u obtener foto de galería cuando hagamos click en la imagen.
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera
        //https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics?hl=ES
        ImageView imgFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFotoEdit);

        String nombre = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreEdit)).getText().toString();
        String notas = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNotasEdit)).getText().toString();
        String telefono = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTlfEdit)).getText().toString();
        String correo = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCorreoEdit)).getText().toString();


        if (nombre.isEmpty() && notas.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Información de contacto vacía", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            try {
                contacto = new Contacto(nombre, notas);
                BaseDeDatos bd = new BaseDeDatos(this);
                bd.anadirContacto(contacto);
                bd.anadirCorreoContacto(new Correo(contacto.getIdentificador(), correo));
                bd.anadirTelefonoContacto(new Telefono(contacto.getIdentificador(), telefono));

                Toast.makeText(this, "Nuevo contacto añadido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Refrescamos el listView de la actividad principal.
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ha habido un problema", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }


    public void onClickFoto(View view) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (permisosConcedidos()) {
                dialogoFoto();
            } else {
                pedirVariosPermisos();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Muestra un diálogo para elegir la fuente de la imagen de contacto: cámara o galería.
     * Dentro de cada opción hace la acción correspondiente.
     */
    private void dialogoFoto() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NuevaPersonaActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Añadir una foto").setPositiveButton(R.string.camara, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent intentFoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (intentFoto.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File foto = null;
                    try{
                        foto = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(foto != null){
                        Uri uriFoto = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NuevaPersonaActivity.this, "com.example.agendaandroid.fileprovider", foto);
                        intentFoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFoto);
                        startActivityForResult(intentFoto, INTENT_CAMARA);
                    }

                }
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.galeria, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent intentGaleria = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intentGaleria, INTENT_GALERIA);
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }



    /*Este método comprueba si los permisos necesarios han sido aceptados o no por el usuario.
    *Solo funciona si la api es mayor o igual a nuestra mínima (23). Devuelve false con solo un permiso denegado.
    * */
    @RequiresApi( api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean permisosConcedidos(){
        for (String permiso : permisos){
            if(checkSelfPermission(permiso) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
    Este método crea una lista de los permisos que aún no tenemos concedidos y los vuelve a pedir..
     */
    @RequiresApi( api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void pedirVariosPermisos(){
        List<String> permisosNoConcedidos = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String permiso : permisos){
            if(checkSelfPermission(permiso) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                permisosNoConcedidos.add(permiso);
            }
        }
        requestPermissions(permisosNoConcedidos.toArray(new String[permisosNoConcedidos.size()]),101);

    }


    @RequiresApi( api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 101){
            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[i])){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                .setMessage("Estos permisos son necesarios para establecer una foto de contacto")
                                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", (dialog, which) -> pedirVariosPermisos())
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Cuando recibe el resultado de la actividad recoge la información y la muestra en el imageView
     * @param requestCode
     * @param resultCode
     * @param data
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch(requestCode){
            case INTENT_CAMARA:
                if (requestCode == INTENT_CAMARA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { ;
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    ImageView imgFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFotoEdit);
                    imgFoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                }
                break;
            case INTENT_GALERIA:
                if((requestCode == INTENT_GALERIA) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data != null)){
                    Uri imagenSeleccionada = data.getData();
                    String[] ruta = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imagenSeleccionada, ruta, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int indice = cursor.getColumnIndex(ruta[0]);
                    String rutaFoto = cursor.getString(indice);
                    cursor.close();

                    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFotoEdit);
                    img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rutaFoto));
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Crea un archivo para las fotos sacadas con la cámara.
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        String hora = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String nombre = "JPEG_" + hora + "_";
        File direccionAlmacenamiento = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imagen = File.createTempFile(nombre, ".jpg", direccionAlmacenamiento);

        direccionActualFoto = imagen.getAbsolutePath();

        return imagen;
    }
</pre>
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.agendaandroid">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <activity android:name=".DetallePersona"></activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.agendaandroid.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".NuevaPersonaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nueva_persona"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.agendaandroid/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Taking photos works just fine, but once I add the code to create the file for the photograph the activity closes after taking the photo and said error appears on Run.

I hope all that info is enough, and thank you very much.

**Edit:** 
I've decided to store the photos in the app's directory to keep it simpler, but it turns out that the Intent I pass into the onActivityResult is null, so it can't get the extras.

```
      Intent intentFoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intentFoto.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File foto = null;
            try{
                foto = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(foto != null){
                Uri uriFoto = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        "com.example.agendaandroid.fileprovider",
                        foto);
                intentFoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFoto);
                startActivityForResult(intentFoto, INTENT_CAMARA);
            }

        }
```

Comment: in which version it fails, getting uri is different in lower APIs. Maybe it causes error. Try   Uri.fromFile(foto) if it helps then you should insert if else statement in your code

Comment: @Jasurbek thanks, where should I insert this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the method to take a photo either from gallery or from the camera looks like this:

```
 private void dialogoFoto() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NuevaPersonaActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Añadir una foto").setPositiveButton(R.string.camara, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, INTENT_CAMARA);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.galeria, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intentGaleria = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intentGaleria, INTENT_GALERIA);
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

And the onActivityResult like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch(requestCode){
            case INTENT_CAMARA:
                if (requestCode == INTENT_CAMARA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    ImageView imgFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFotoEdit);
                    imgFoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }
                break;
            case INTENT_GALERIA:
                if((requestCode == INTENT_GALERIA) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data != null)){
                    Uri imagenSeleccionada = data.getData();
                    String[] ruta = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imagenSeleccionada, ruta, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int indice = cursor.getColumnIndex(ruta[0]);
                    String rutaFoto = cursor.getString(indice);
                    cursor.close();

                    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFotoEdit);
                    img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rutaFoto));
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Uri uriFoto = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NuevaPersonaActivity.this, "com.example.agendaandroid.fileprovider", foto);
                    intentFoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFoto);
                    startActivityForResult(intentFoto, INTENT_CAMARA);
```

You are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Your photo should be written to the location that you provided.

```
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

You are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. There should not be any extras. Your photo should be written to the location that you provided in the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra. Use your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso) to load it into your `ImageView`.