# camera code with interface to select from album or camera

Tags: android

Has anyone implelemented a UI where you can choose from album or camera and then the camera opens and you can click and then click on a use button to use that. Please give any suggestions or reference project links

Thanks 
Max

Comment: What you have tried to so far?

Comment: The answer to your question, (if anyone has implemented this) is surely yes. I have seen this in apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code to call UI to select camera or gallery,

```
private void openAddPhoto() {

            String[] addPhoto=new String[]{ "Camera" , "Gallery" };
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.method));

            dialog.setItems(addPhoto,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    if(id==0){
                        // Call camera Intent
                    }
                    if(id==1){
                        //call gallery
                    }
                }
            });     

            dialog.setNeutralButton("cancel",new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();               
                }});
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Here is a former question & answer for the select-dialog: [Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image)
2. just use this [Camera Preview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html) sample from google to get an image.
3. write that image to sd card then with the code from this sample: [DataStorage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)
4. and then use an image-view layout to display the former written file: [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)