# Accessing intent result name and icon

Tags: android

I need a UI that merges together all the available intent matches for both cameras and galleries. I've successfully acquired a list of intents for each, and merged them together ( see [Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image)).

Given the merged list of intents, how do I then get the name of the app, and a reference to its icon so I can display them in the UI? I've been digging around in the intents but I can only see the class name, not the friendly name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is...

ResolveInfo.loadLabel()

ResolveInfo.icon