# pick gallery image and convert to bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, bitmapimage

I am trying to pick an image from the gallery, convert it to a `Bitmap`, and display it in an `ImageView`.

the below code is used to pick image from the gallery

```
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);`
```

In `onActivityResult` I am converting it into a `Bitmap` and displaying it in the `ImageView`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;//returning null for below statement
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.toString(), options);
            productItemImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The value in the selected image Uri is returned as "content://media/external/images/media/3647"

`productItemImage` is my `ImageView` to which I am displaying the `Bitmap`. There is no error but the bitmap is returning null.

Please Help

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be your `super.onActivityResult()` call in your `onActivityResult()` function.

Here is an answer I wrote last year that gives a complete example of what you want to do, plus allows you to choose from the camera as well as the gallery: [Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image/12347567#12347567) (This answer has a high score, so I think it will be helpful to you).

Comment: sorry that was a typing error in the question.. I have corrected it.. but the problem still exists

Comment: Check the edit of my answer, and go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image/12347567#12347567