# Photos taken are smaller than expected in Android camera

Tags: android

I've created my own controller to take pictures with the android camera. My problem is that the output shows a smaller image than expected. I've checked the width and height of my bitmap like this:

```
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
```

This outputs `w = 480` and `h = 640` which I assume is the size in pixels. This is my method for taking the picture

```
public void takePicture() {
        Log.i("Camera View: ", "Take Picture");
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                if (null != callback) {
                    callback.onJpegPictureTaken(data, camera);

                }
            }
        });
 }
```

Where my `Activity` subscribes to this event `onJpegPictureTaken`

```
    @Override
    public void onJpegPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ImageEditing.class);
        i.putExtra("image", data);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

The purpose of this is to launch a new `Activity` in order to edit the image, like zooming and dragging. This ImageEditing.class gets the picture like this:

```
flipped = flipByteArrayNintyDegress(getIntent().getExtras()
                .getByteArray("image"));

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(flipped, 0, flipped.length);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        image.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I first thought that my `ImageView` had some restriction due to the height and width of the `ImageView`, but that is not the case. Here is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the result when I capture the image

[image]
 Does anybody know what's going on here? Why is the image being scaled?

Comment: your image is sooooo meta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `data` returned to `onJpegPictureTaken()` is intended as a thumbnail representation. You are receiving one of the sizes reported by `getSupportedJpegThumbnailSizes()` in the [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html). There is not enough heap memory in your camera to send an entire full-resolution image through a `byte[]` array, even compressed/encoded as a Jpeg image. Therefore, the thumbnail is sent as a quick way to preview the result. You have to find the storage location of the image in order to access it at full resolution.

Furthermore, even then you will have to open it with a scale factor in the `BitmapFactory.Options` in order to fit it memory as a `Bitmap`.

Also check `setPictureSize()` on the [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) and check the supported sizes available with `getSupportedPictureSizes()`.

---

**Let Android Take the Picture For You**:

You can cause the Android System Camera Application to take a full-resolution picture and return to your `Activity` afterwards using examples such as this: [Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image/12347567#12347567). Your `Activity` will have access to the full-resolution saved image file after it is captured by the camera.

In order to flip or rotate this image in full resolution (which is impossible to open at that size as a `Bitmap`), you can modify the EXIF data describing AFine transformations. This will not modify the actual pixel data, but will change the way it gets displayed on most systems. There are several examples of how to read and write EXIF data on this site but I do not have a code example that I have used available at this time.

Comment: So I need to save the image inside the `onJpegPictureTaken()` ?

Comment: No. That will not help. The thumbnail data you get in that function will not get larger no matter what you do with it. You may be able to make it larger with `setPictureSize()`, but not much larger.

Answer (score 0):

What about the implementation of flipByteArrayNintyDegress?

/Yaron

Comment: The output resolution is the same as the input res.