# Nullpointer exception on getPackageManger method while using in openImageIntent method to select image either from camera or gallary

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm calling image intent method to get the options of camera or gallary while clicking on image view.I found the code here
[Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image)
user David Manpearl

and this is the code I'm using

```
public static final int YOUR_SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE=222;

 public void openImageIntent1() {

        // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "userDir" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        final String fname = "img_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

            // Camera.
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }

            // Filesystem.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

            // Add the camera options.
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 222);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if(requestCode == 222) {
                    final boolean isCamera;
                    if(data == null)
                        isCamera = true;
                    else {
                        final String action = data.getAction();
                        if(action == null)
                            isCamera = false;
                        else
                            isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                    Uri selectedImageUri;
                    if(isCamera)
                        selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                    else
                        selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this ,getting error on final `PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager()` line.

Can you please help?
Thank you

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and how you're calling `openImageIntent1()` e.g. how you initialize the object you call the method on.

Comment: I'm calling this method in another class by making object of this call

Answer (score 1):

> I'm calling this method in another class by making object of this call

Never instantiate an `Activity` with `new`. It won't get properly initialized, and calling any activity or context method won't work. So it's no good for anything you'd want to use it for.

Instead, pass in a `Context` as a parameter to methods that need it like this.

To instantiate an activity, use `startActivity()` with `Intent`.