# Cannot set ImageView by Capture Camera from Intent.createChooser

Tags: android, android-intent

Im reaching the way how to set image for ImageView from Camera or Gallery without using AlertDialog or handle two buttons for too intent.

So, I found the Intent.createChooser from https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2 or [Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image/12347567#12347567)

Everything working perfect when i was selected image from Gallery, but from Camera , always RunExceptionError.

Here are my classes:
MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_ID = 234;
    ImageView image;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    onPickImage(v);
                }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
    }
    public void onPickImage(View view) throws IOException{
        Intent chooseIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(this);
        startActivityForResult(chooseIntent,PICK_IMAGE_ID);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case PICK_IMAGE_ID:

                    Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
}
```

ImagePicker.java

```
public class ImagePicker {
    private static final int DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY = 400;        // min pixels
    private static final String TAG = "ImagePicker";
    private static final String TEMP_IMAGE_NAME = "tempImage";

    public static int minWidthQuality = DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY;

    public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
        Intent chooserIntent = null;

        List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
        intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
        intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

        if (intentList.size() > 0) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                    context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_text));
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        }
        return chooserIntent;
    }

    private static List<Intent> addIntentsToList(Context context, List<Intent> list, Intent intent) {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetedIntent = new Intent(intent);
            targetedIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            list.add(targetedIntent);
            Log.d(TAG, "Intent: " + intent.getAction() + " package: " + packageName);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static Bitmap getImageFromResult(Context context, int resultCode,
                                            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageFromResult, resultCode: " + resultCode);
        Bitmap bm = null;
        File imageFile = getTempFile(context);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage;
            boolean isCamera = imageReturnedIntent == null;
            if (isCamera) {     /** CAMERA **/
                selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            } else {            /** ALBUM **/
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "selectedImage: " + selectedImage);

            bm = getImageResized(context, selectedImage);
            int rotation = getRotation(context, selectedImage, isCamera);
            bm = rotate(bm, rotation);
        }
        return bm;
    }

    private static File getTempFile(Context context) {
        File imageFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), TEMP_IMAGE_NAME);
        imageFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        return imageFile;
    }

    private static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Context context, Uri theUri, int sampleSize) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
        try {
            fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(theUri, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
                fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);

        Log.d(TAG, options.inSampleSize + " sample method bitmap ... " +
                actuallyUsableBitmap.getWidth() + " " + actuallyUsableBitmap.getHeight());

        return actuallyUsableBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Resize to avoid using too much memory loading big images (e.g.: 2560*1920)
     **/
    private static Bitmap getImageResized(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        int[] sampleSizes = new int[]{5, 3, 2, 1};
        int i = -1;
        do {
            i++;
            bm = decodeBitmap(context, selectedImage, sampleSizes[i]);
            Log.d(TAG, "resizer: new bitmap width = " + bm.getWidth());
        } while (bm.getWidth() < minWidthQuality && i < sampleSizes.length);
        return bm;
    }

    private static int getRotation(Context context, Uri imageUri, boolean isCamera) {
        int rotation;
        if (isCamera) {
            rotation = getRotationFromCamera(context, imageUri);
        } else {
            rotation = getRotationFromGallery(context, imageUri);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Image rotation: " + rotation);
        return rotation;
    }

    private static int getRotationFromCamera(Context context, Uri imageFile) {
        int rotate = 0;
        try {

            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageFile, null);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getPath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }

    public static int getRotationFromGallery(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
        String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, columns, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) return 0;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);
        return cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
    }

    private static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bm, int rotation) {
        if (rotation != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            return bmOut;
        }
        return bm;
    }
}
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
10-10 22:30:13.038  27208-27208/com.example.tri.intentchooser W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.tri.intentchooser-2/lib/arm
10-10 22:30:13.156  27208-27223/com.example.tri.intentchooser D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-10 22:30:13.430  27208-27223/com.example.tri.intentchooser I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 09/02/15, 76f806e, Ibddc658e36
10-10 22:30:13.468  27208-27223/com.example.tri.intentchooser I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-10 22:30:38.589  27208-27208/com.example.tri.intentchooser D/ImagePicker﹕ Intent: android.intent.action.PICK package: com.google.android.apps.photos
10-10 22:30:38.590  27208-27208/com.example.tri.intentchooser D/ImagePicker﹕ Intent: android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE package: com.google.android.GoogleCamera
10-10 22:30:38.620  27208-27215/com.example.tri.intentchooser W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 25.571ms
10-10 22:30:39.827  27208-27223/com.example.tri.intentchooser E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaefbc490
10-10 22:30:48.058  27208-27208/com.example.tri.intentchooser D/ImagePicker﹕ getImageFromResult, resultCode: -1
10-10 22:30:48.074  27208-27208/com.example.tri.intentchooser D/ImagePicker﹕ selectedImage: null
10-10 22:30:48.082  27208-27208/com.example.tri.intentchooser D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-10 22:30:48.098  27208-27208/com.example.tri.intentchooser E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tri.intentchooser, PID: 27208
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.tri.intentchooser/com.example.tri.intentchooser.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.tri.intentchooser/com.example.tri.intentchooser.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.tri.intentchooser/com.example.tri.intentchooser.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3089)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
            at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:922)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:865)
            at com.example.tri.intentchooser.ImagePicker.decodeBitmap(ImagePicker.java:110)
            at com.example.tri.intentchooser.ImagePicker.getImageResized(ImagePicker.java:133)
            at com.example.tri.intentchooser.ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(ImagePicker.java:90)
            at com.example.tri.intentchooser.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:62)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3089)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I had look for `"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity"` but not luck for it, also it may relating to the log `selectedImage = NULL`.

Please show me any idea or advise for it.
Thanks.