# How to make a dialog with icons like the one in Whatsapp?

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog

I want to display a Dialog that will look like this one from Whatsapp:

[image: Whatsapp screenshot]
I tried using an xml file with two `ImageButton`s and use it in the `alert.setView` method, but the buttons couldn't access the functions I wanted them to activate...
Any other idea or a way to access the functions?

Comment: That's an intent chooser. Look here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I need to let the user choose between taking a picture with the camera or selecting an existing picture from the gallery. What `ACTION` should I use?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Thanks man (: