# android camera intent stuck on confirmation

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I'm using a chooser to allow the user to pick a photo from his gallery or take a new one using his camera (I copied the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347567/6056221)).
Picking an image from the gallery works perfect. The problem is that when I capture an image with the camera It's not returning to the app and just stays in the confirmation screen...
I actually don't even need this screen to be displayed in the first place...
Can I somehow disable it or (if not) just make the `Done` button work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @NaN It's in the link... I didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow disable it

No.

> just make the Done button work?

Contact the developers of your camera app, and point out the bug. Perhaps someday they will fix it.

You are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. This launches a third-party camera app, to take a picture. There thousands of Android device models. These ship with hundreds of different pre-installed camera apps, and there are many more available for download from the Play Store and elsewhere. Any could be the one that handles a given `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request, and any of them can have bugs.

Comment: I tried other camera apps as well... In the other apps, It shows the capture animation but just stays in the app. Maybe I should tell the camera I need a photo back or something? I thought I handled it with the `startActivityForResult` call...

Comment: @Dotan: You are picking a series of buggy camera apps. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not very reliable, due to buggy camera apps.

Comment: Can you suggest a trusted app so I can test that's really a bug in the camera app?

Comment: @Dotan: I have only used `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with pre-installed camera apps. I have not had a problem with it using Nexus devices. Beyond that, I avoid `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: So can you suggest a different approach to get a picture from the camera?

Comment: @Dotan: Use the camera APIs directly, whether yourself of through a library, like [mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2).