# Picking a image from Camera works, but not from the Gallary [VIDEO DEMO]

Tags: android

I have followed some examples on SO of how to retrive an image from Camera or Gallary. The camera part works, but the gallary part dosn't. The code seems very diffuclt to understand for me, so I dont know what exactly to look after.

I also have the needed permissions in my manifest.

Here is a video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOoY1y4W86w

**ImagePicker(View V), intent/choosers, files, URIS**

```
public void ImagePicker(View v) {

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            final File rootdir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TravelDiary" + File.separator);
            rootdir.mkdirs();
            final String filename = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            final File sdImageMainDirecotry = new File(rootdir, filename);
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirecotry);
            Log.d("TAG", "IM HERE 1");

            //camera
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>();
            final Intent CameraCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listcam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(CameraCaptureIntent, 0);
            Log.d("TAG", "IM HERE 2");


            for (ResolveInfo res : listcam) {

                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(CameraCaptureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
                Log.d("TAG", "IM HERE 3");
            }


            //Gallary
            final Intent imageChooser = new Intent();
            imageChooser.setType("image/*");
            imageChooser.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(imageChooser, "Select Source");

            // Add the camera options.

            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_FROM_GALLARY);


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "External storage not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**onActivityResult():**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FROM_GALLARY) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (data == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else {
                    isCamera = action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if (isCamera) {

                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageUri.getPath(), options);
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                pic.setBackground(drawable);

            } else {
                selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                Log.d("ImageURI", selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                try {

                    InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);

                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                    pic.setBackground(drawable);


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to pick image from Gallery.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   //Here PICK_FROM_GALLERY is a requestCode
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

In onActivityResult():

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
      if (data.getData() != null) {
           mImageUri = data.getData();
      } else {
          //showing toast when unable to capture the image
           Debug.toastValid(context, "Unable to upload Image Please Try again ...");
      }
}
```

Comment: This dont work with the code I have. Have you seen my code?

Comment: Where are you passing intent action for gallery...? Please c my answer,there i m passing action to an intent.

Comment: I have it here: `final Intent imageChooser = new Intent();
                imageChooser.setType("image/*");
                imageChooser.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

and then I do `Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(imageChooser, "Select Source");`

Comment: Then what's the problem...Are you getting result ok for gallery?

Comment: I made a video for you, that shows you what is going on (:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOoY1y4W86w