# How can I send picture from android application via MMS?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android)

How can I send a picture from android application via MMS? I found this code but I don't know how can I insert picture inside it when a user take the picture from Gallery of the mobile?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching Google is a good way to find answers to questions like this.

What you want to do is call startActivityForResult() to allow the user to pick a photo, then in onActivityResult() send the intent with the selected photo.  See this: [android pick images from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5309190/758458)