# Browser SDcard in android application

Tags: android

Thanks in advance,
How to browser the sd card in android for select a .txt file from any sdcard location..
This feature like selecting a image from media location and set image over image view.
Thanks again..

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mandfilebrowser/

Comment: Well, i found answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

> How to browser the sd card in android for select a .txt file from any sdcard location

Either write your own activity to do this, or integrate with a third-party app that does this (e.g., [OIFileManager](http://openintents.org/en/filemanager)), or find a third-party JAR that offers this.