# How to pick photo from gallery with SL4A?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I'm using SL4A to code a tool to upload images from the gallery to my own image service. But I can't figure out how I can get an image from the gallery. I think I need intents for that, but I can't find anything related to that on the internet.
(Oh yeah, I'm using Python.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would be right; SL4A APIs such as `makeIntent()`, `startActivityForResult()` and `startActivityForResultIntent()` will be of interest to you. It's just a quick Google or two to find the Intent details for fetching images, eg., [android pick images from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery)

Personally I tried various alternative of:

```
intent = droid.makeIntent('ACTION_GET_CONTENT',"",'image/*')
result = droid.startActivityForResultIntent(intent)
```

But it didn't like me.... I got something along the lines of `No activity found ...`, which would suggest the need to create an Intent Chooser, which is [apparently impossible](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=588) **:/**

Apologies that I can't be of much more use.

Good luck!

Comment: I managed to do it now. I had to use the following code:


`droid.startActivityForResult('android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT', None, '*/*')`


So now I can not only choose from the gallery, but also from almost every other app that lets me choose content, like ES File Explorer etc. :)