# Knowing if picture or text was send under Android

Tags: android

I have to create a program who allow me to know if the user sent a message or a picture (or another thing, but I'll begin with these two)

When the user touch the "Send" button, I start a new *intent* and play with *intent-filter* to know wich kind of data was send. I'm aware of that.

But the question is : What should I put in my *activity_main.xml* to allow the user to put differents kinds of data ?

I don't really have any idea how to do this. 
Please, be indulgant, I'm a beginner with Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you will want to have a field to allow the user to enter text and an option to select a picture.

In general, an introduction to Android inputs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html

For the text field you will want to use the EditText object:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

A simple example of a button and a text field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
  <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This would display a text entry field for the users to select and type and a button, in this case used to send the text they typed.

For the picture you might want to add another button in your XML which launches an Intent to select a picture. Here is an example Intent for that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

That code is from:  [android pick images from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery)
Which also covers how to handle the image that the user selected from the Intent.

When the user clicks your "Send" button, you could grab the contents of your EditText to see if the user typed anything, and your code will know whether or not the user performed the PICK_IMAGE intent, that would allow you to determine whether a picture or text was sent.