# File.listFiles returns null when it shouldn't

Tags: android, filesystems, android-permissions

I am trying to get list of files existing in the Phone Pictures folder (internal storage, no SDCard inserted) using this:

```
 File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
 File[] files = file.listFiles();
```

but files value is always being null.
I also add this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `File file = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES ).getAbsoluteFile()));`. That is terrible code. Change to `File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

Comment: What is the value of file.getAbsolutePath() using your code?

Comment: Does the directory contain files?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures, is this the path to access the internal memory Pictures folder?

Comment: Which Android version in use?

Comment: `thanks in advance`?? Bad habit.

Comment: two question marks? Bad habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting Android SDK >=23 you need to take permission at run-time.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: what permission do I need? WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? already tried that from code, nothing changed

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE this permission in AndroidManifest.xml and take permission at run-time

Answer (score 1):

It returns null as `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` will/is supposed to handle files from external storage like SD card..as you are stating no sd card is inserted

Comment: From external storage indeed. But never from an SD card.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement..??I assume you want to list pictures from internal storage assuming you mentioned no SD card

Comment: The function name sais it all: from external storage.

Answer (score 0):

As Abhishek Aryan suggested, I am using Android SDK >=23  so I had to obtain permissions using code:

```
  boolean grantedAll = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
if (!grantedAll)
   {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
   }
```