# Android Error While using ExifInterface

Tags: android

I am trying to check the orientation of bitmap and flip it if there is a need, but I have error while applying the code. Here is my code while i am trying to flipp the image using ExifInterface:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void flipping(Bitmap b)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
        try {

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(bs);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            switch(orientation) {

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotateImage(b, 90);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotateImage(b, 180);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotateImage(b, 270);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

                default:
                    break;
            }

            encoding();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    }
```

And here is the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V in class Landroid/media/ExifInterface; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.media.ExifInterface' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
                                                                       at com.sara.image_test.MainActivity.flipping(MainActivity.java:181)
                                                                       at com.sara.image_test.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7165)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4994)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are attempting to use `android.media.ExifInterface`. On Android 7.0+ (API Level 24), that class is safe to use and has a constructor that takes an `InputStream`. Apparently, you are running your app on an older device. That results in two problems:

1. The older device will not have that constructor
2. `ExifInterface` has security flaws on older devices, opening your app up to malware attacks

Use `android.support.media.ExifInterface` instead. It is from the [support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#exif) (`com.android.support:exifinterface`, specifically). It offers a constructor taking an `InputStream` that works on all supported versions of Android. And, it bypasses the security bug on older devices.

Comment: thanks, it is not giving errors anymore. But it returns 0 always on all images.

Comment: @SalehRefaai: That is not surprising, since a `Bitmap` does not have any EXIF headers. You already threw away any EXIF data when you loaded the `Bitmap` from wherever it came from. Use `ExifInterface` on the original source of the data, not the `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 55):

for **AndroidX** use

```
androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface
```

Import this dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.2'
```

Comment: Thanks. The official docs are so poor no mention of the dependency.

Comment: The latest version is available at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/exifinterface

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your build.gradle file

```
compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.0"
```

for me it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The ExifInterface constructor being used in your code sample:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
```

was added in SDK level 24.

But it looks like the code is being run on a device with an earlier version of Android than 24.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)