# Right place to put `@SuppressLint("ExifInterface")`?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, suppress-warnings

Android Studio 4.1 suggests avoiding using `android.media.exifinterface` and using `android.support.media.exifinterface` instead. We may want to suppress it, e.g., if the project has min SDK API 24, and [it is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246110/android-error-while-using-exifinterface) that `android.media.exifinterface` is fine for API 24 and above.

Android Studio's context menu gives `Add @SuppressLint("ExifInterface")` but nothing happens on clicking that. Adding `@SuppressLint("ExifInterface")` in several places (trying one at a time, of course) doesn't work, e.g.,

- the line immediately above the `import android.media.exifinterface;` statement
- the line before the `package` line at the top of the whole file

Where is the right place to add this @SuppressLint annotation?

Comment: I think you would need to suppress it at the module level, using `build.gradle` or `lint-baseline.xml` or something. I don't see an option for applying that annotation to an `import` statement, which I assume is where you are seeing it. FWIW, I filed [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184290317) to get that class reference updated -- I was surprised to see a reference to the old `android.support.media.ExifInterface` floating around.

Comment: Thanks, doing it in the `build.gradle` worked. Yes. the lint suggestion was coming at the import statement. If you'd like to write it as answer, I can accept that.

Comment: FWIW, I starred the issue you filed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I cannot find a place for the `@SuppressLint` that works to suppress a Lint warning on an `import` statement.

In this case, my guess is that you would want to be suppressing this module-wide anyway. I cannot think of a scenario where you would want to use the framework `ExifInterface` in some places and the library `ExifInterface` in others. So, you could use stuff [like `lint.xml`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#pref) or [`lintOptions` in the module's `build.gradle` file](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#gradle) to suppress it for the entire module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//noinspection ExifInterface
import android.media.exifinterface;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).