# Fetching images and displaying in gridview

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.1

How do I select images from the memory and display those selected images dynamically across a gridview? 
Sorry if this is a duplicate thread because I couldn't find any solutions. If there are any other closed threads, please provide the link.
Thank you :)

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309217/7783718).

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I know how to create the intent and open the chooser panel. My question is how do I fetch those multiple images and display them in a gridview.

Comment: [Android Multiple Images Selector](https://github.com/zfdang/android-multiple-images-selector) you can use this Library.