# How to get image from gallery/file manager into Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I'd like to get an image content from system gallery and put it in an imageview in the FragmentActivity.
I'm trying to do so with an implicit intent, however I don't get any data in onActivityResult method. My code:

```
 chooseFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

and when i used the startAactivityForResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageInput.setImageBitmap(image);
    } else if (resultCode == PICK_CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(ImageInput);
    }
}
```

this is what i get
and no image showing up on my imageview
is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android pick images from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. This code will work fine below `SDK 24` you need to use content provider for devices greater than that.

P.S: After you setup content provider you need to convert the content URI to absolute path if you want to use it in picasso.

Hope this helped!