# How do i acces files in Xamarin.Form app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am current writing a small tool with Xamarin Form (Android) that takes some file content and displays them in some specific way.
In these files i have some cross-links (e.g. jpeg-images) that should be embedded in the display of the file.

To get the main file i am using "CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile()".
It returns an "FileData" object, which allready has the main file contents, plus the URI of that file.

If there is a cross-link in that file i can assume that the linked file is in the same folder as the main file.

My idea (taking jpeg as example) to get the base-folder of the file and append the name of the jpeg and then open the image as stream:

```
ImagePath = Path.Combine(baseFolder.Trim(), imageFile.Trim());

try
{
    fileStream = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    fileStream.DisposeWith(Disposables);

    ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => fileStream);
    ShowImage = true;
}
catch
{
    // Ignore
}
```

Unfortunatelly FileStream failes, and claims it could not find the containing directory.

The path towards to JPG look like this:

```
/document/0F1E-120D/TestData/P1060371.jpg
```

The file path i get from the Picker is:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/0F1E-120D%3ATestData%2FTestFile.txt
```

Using that a an URI i can extract the local path:

```
/document/0F1E-120D:TestData/TestFile.txt
```

When removing the file name i get

```
/document/0F1E-120D:TestData
```

***Obviously that path is invalid...***

Any hint on how i can get a valid path i can feed into the FileStream for reading the file?
Any more hints about that permissions i have to take care? Currently i have set READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Do you want to access the path like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app/files/Documents` or `/storage/emulated/0/Documents`? If you want to access the seond path, you can get it by `Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath`

Comment: What t´d rather like to do is to allow the use to select the directory. I´ve created a simple folder browser to set the directory.

I´ve done some changes meanwhile and the path looks like

/storage/1EE7-170F/TestFile.txt

That is working for now to read the files...

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NetStandard2.0` you use this code

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

it also applied to specific platform(e.g: Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, etc)

Comment: Accessing the file is not the problem. The problem is that i somehow need to find out the filepath from the URI mentioned above.

Comment: If you got the URI from `onActivityResult` you can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309965/4778712)