# How to take an image from gallery

Tags: android, image, android-studio, bitmap

I need to pick an image from the gallery of the phone in order to do some stuff with that.
For this purpose I tried to follow what is inside this [android pick images from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery) thread but I think it's too old, probably I need to use the intent anyway but I don't understand how and how to pass the image picked to a bitmap variable.
Precisely I need to take an image and then convert it to bitmap and do other stuff (ml algorithms).
Thanks.

Comment: Use [this answer from your linked-to question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309217/115145). In `onActivityResult()`, if you got an image (`RESULT_OK`), pass it to your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso) to have it load the image on a background thread and give you a `Bitmap` to use.

Comment: Thank you, later on I will try and let you know the results!

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, I'm looking at this https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html#background-threads but I cannot understand how to convert the selected image into a bitmap, have you any suggestion?

Comment: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/SimpleTarget.html

Comment: But when I take the picture then I should do all the stuffs in onActivityResult() or come back to the MainActivity?

Comment: My typical approach would be "none of the above": have a singleton repository object handle the network I/O and get you your bitmap. I suspect your app's architecture is not using repositories and things like that, so I cannot really answer your question.

Comment: No, infact, because it just need to select an image from the gallery and make some inferences with ml algorithms. I just need that for personal purpose, it surely won't go to the store.