# Android - show image in android gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to open a photo, and I have red that I can use the default android gallery, but I can't get it work.
I have looked at severals forums, and finally I get this code, but it opens a black image.
I'm using api minimum 16 and target 29, testing on api 29.
Someone can help me?
Thanks.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://"+"/storage/emulated/0/photo.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Already tried Uri.fromFile() but doesn't work.

Comment: what api are you using?

Comment: you can do Uri.fromFile()

Comment: @Jerson i have updated the post

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery

Comment: @Jerson no, I need to display the image in the gallery, not picking it

Comment: ok added answer

Comment: `I have red that I can use the default android gallery,` You can use nothing as ACTION_VIEW lets the user choose from all apps that can display an image.

Comment: `"content://"+"/storage/emulated/0/photo.jpg"` That is not the way make a content scheme from a file system path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working code, thanks to all to let me know the FileProvider

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myproject.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

res/xml/filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path path="/" name="myInternalMemory" />
</paths>
```

MainActivity.java

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.myproject.myapp.fileprovider", new File(filenamePath));
context.grantUriPermission("com.myproject.myapp.fileprovider", contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(contentUri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//support from Android 4.1 (API level 16) to Android 5.1 (API level 22) inclusive
intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", contentUri));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Uri.fromFile() instead

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/photo.jpg")), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

but you will get FileURIExposed error so you need to add this code in your oncreate()

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build);
```

Note: don't use hardcoded path use [Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment)

Not the best answer but its work well

Comment: No this will not work as it will throw a FileUriExposedException when strict mode not used. And of course you will not use a strict mode hack but a FileProvider.

Comment: i tried that on but it seems work, but not recommend to disable strictmode, although it can be achieve using file provider as you said

Comment: You should use a FileProvider and not that hack. That's it.

Comment: @Jerson I don't use hardcoded path in my app but I used it in this post to be more readable for you

Comment: @Jerson your second code gives me: cannot resolve symbol "build", can you provide an example about FileProvider?