# Why selected image from the gallery is not showing?

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that went I click the button it will go to the gallery and whatever Choose in the gallery it will display on the image view the problem is when I select an image in my gallery and the size is 3mb up it will not display in an image view. Is there a way that I can display it even if the size is 3MB up?

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery

Comment: 3mb== 3 milli bit?

Comment: thank you for answering sir. 3mb is 3 megabyte, when the size of the image is 3megabyte up it will not display in the image view

Comment: @SaurabhDhage Thank you yep I was using the code and it works perfectly. But the problem is when  the size of the image is 3 megabyte or higher the image will not display.

Comment: `3mb is 3 megabyte` Sorry. Sadly you did not get the point. 3MB would be 3 mega byte.

Comment: And it is not the size of the image file but the resolution of the image described by it that prevents the generation of a bitmap. The bitmap would become to big for available memory. Solution: scale it down.

Answer (score 0):

are you using any particular library for picking image from your gallery!?

Comment: I'm not using any particular library sir.

Comment: try using this library ```implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'```