# How to open android camera with access to gallery

Tags: android, camera

When we open device camera we got multiple options to select like settings or access to gallery.
How to show that by calling camera intent .
Please have look to image.
Please help.![image]

Comment: see if this topic help your idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932329/initiate-camera-intent-with-the-gallery-icon

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE);
```

Comment: It's better to add some explanations.