# How to make intent chooser for camera or gallery application in android like whatsapp editprofile?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, dialog, gallery

I am developing an application where i need to have a dialog choose for uploading image from gallery or camera. I have found kind of solution here [Dialog to pick image from gallery or from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera) but the problem is here there is clash in comparing which action is chosen by user.

I would like to know if i can modify in this code and get some result to differentiate either gallery or camera is chosen and then apply action.

Answer (score 13):

Create new method into Main Activity File called “selectImage()”..for choose option

```
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Now we need return back to our activity with proper Result.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        btmapOptions);

                // bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, MainActivity.this);
            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
}
```

Add this method  in onactivity()

```
 public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity
            .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: follow this one it will give more idea http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample/

Comment: what getPath(Uri uri, Context context) does? I can't use it on my activity.

Comment: Managed to make work by following this: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just an advice when you call `startActivityForResult()` to take a photo with camera:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```

Notice that the `startActivityForResult()` method is protected by a condition that calls `resolveActivity()`, which returns the first activity component that can handle the intent. Performing this check is important because if you call `startActivityForResult()` using an intent that no app can handle, your app will crash. So as long as the result is not null, it's safe to use the intent.