# Intent chooser for picking image from gallery or camera not working on some devices

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I have created an intent chooser for picking any image from gallery or camera. It is working fine on emulator and other devices but when I tested it with redmi note 4, it shows "no apps can perform this action".

Code is here -

```
   try {
        f = createImageFile();
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        grantUriPermission("com.android.camera", outputFileUri,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        if (outputFileUri != null) {
            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            List<ResolveInfo> listCam = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
                if (outputFileUri != null)
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                allIntents.add(intent);
            }
        }
        allIntents.addAll(getGalleryIntents(getPackageManager(), false));
        Intent target;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            target = new Intent();
        else {
            target = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
            allIntents.remove(allIntents.size() - 1);
        }
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Select Source");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQ_PICK_IMAGE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        f = null;
        outputFileUri = null;
    }


  public static List<Intent> getGalleryIntents(@NonNull PackageManager packageManager, boolean includeDocuments) {
    List<Intent> intents = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        intents.add(intent);
    }
    if (!includeDocuments) {
        for (Intent intent : intents) {
            if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")) {
                intents.remove(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return intents;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}

abstract class AlbumStorageDirFactory {
    public abstract File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName);
}

public final class BaseAlbumDirFactory extends AlbumStorageDirFactory {
    // Standard storage location for digital camera files
    private static final String CAMERA_DIR = "/dcim/";

    @Override
    public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + CAMERA_DIR + albumName);
    }
}

public final class FroyoAlbumDirFactory extends AlbumStorageDirFactory {
    @Override
    public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        return new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    }
}

private File getAlbumDir() {
    File storageDir = null;
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());
        if (storageDir != null)
            if (!storageDir.mkdirs())
                if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                    Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
    } else Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    return storageDir;
}
```

Please help! 
Am I missing something?

Comment: can you post the code of getGalleryIntents function?

Comment: sure please wait

Comment: now its available

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27874114/4407266

Comment: I appreciate this but its not a solution. Its an alternative.

Comment: @Sar please upload createimagefile() code

Comment: Available now ...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but then I realized it was storage permission issue.I modified my code by adding an if condition.

Try this

```
image_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isImageSelect =false;
            //checking if permission is granted for write_external_storage
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(NewMemberActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                selectImage();
            }
            else{
                //Requesting Permission for write_external_storage
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(NewMemberActivity.this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
            }
        }
    });
```