# How to upload particular image on particular imageView click from gallery and camera in android

Tags: android, performance, android-camera, android-imageview, image-gallery

i have 4 diffrent imageview and try to click on all to upload diffrent images like LIcence,Rc,Profile  etc . I want to uploaded image from gallery or camera dialog..
 like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9iGh.jpg) layout. 
like uper layout example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [take picture from camera and choose from gallery and display in Image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304007/take-picture-from-camera-and-choose-from-gallery-and-display-in-image-view)

Comment: post your code ..

Comment: i have 4 imageview and try to click all of imageview to bind diffrent images like licence ,Rc,Profile pic from caemra of gallery @JaydeepPatel

Comment: i have 4 imageview and try to click all of imageview to bind diffrent images like licence ,Rc,Profile pic from caemra of gallery @DarshanKachhadiya

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27874114/4407266

Comment: i have 4 imageview and try to click all of imageview to bind diffrent images like licence ,Rc,Profile pic from caemra of gallery @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Comment: please see mention Layout Image @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Comment: Please see maintion layout @Rushi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my updated answer. This is just an example. Hope you understand from this

```
  ImageView profile_pic;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE1 = 100;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE2 = 101;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE3 = 102;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE4 = 103;





picture1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture1);
picture2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture2);
picture3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture3);
picture4 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture4);
picture1.setOnClickListener(this);
picture2.setOnClickListener(this);
picture3.setOnClickListener(this);
picture4.setOnClickListener(this);







@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.picture1) {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE1);
        }

         if (v.getId() == R.id.picture2) {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE2);
        }
         if (v.getId() == R.id.picture3) {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE3);
        }

         if (v.getId() == R.id.picture4) {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE4);
        }


    }




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE1) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                String path = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                Log.e("image path", path + "");
                pricture1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        } 

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE2) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                String path = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                Log.e("image path", path + "");
                picture2.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        } 

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE3) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                String path = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                Log.e("image path", path + "");
                picture3.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        } 

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE4) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                String path = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                Log.e("image path", path + "");
                picture4.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i have 4 imageview and try to click all of imageview to bind diffrent images like licence ,Rc,Profile picture from caemra of gallery

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_upld_license" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="80dp" android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_upld_rc" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="80dp" android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:layout_below="@id/iv_upld_license" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: please see mention Layout Image @paras

Comment: You can declare different codes for different buttons. Then startActivityForResult and pass the code. Then check the returned code and set the image on different image views. Like I only used one button for the camera and one for the gallery.

Comment: forget about buttons ,i want to click on each and every imageview and select image from camera or galery and set on imageview which imageview clicked https://stackoverflow.com/users/8091876/paras-watts

Comment: Whether click on button or ImageView . You have to declare different image picking codes and then pass those codes in startActivityForResults. For four ImageView use four different codes and get those codes in onActivityResult. Then based on returned codes set the image on ImageView

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Since you are using recyclerview or listview kind of view, you can associate tag to each viewholder and then use that tag for resolving imageview. Now you can get unique tag based on position in view. For eg in recyclerview you can use getAdapterPosition().

Associate OnClicks of each imageview with a request code. In onActivityResult resolve them and put images accordingly.

Comment: i was trying this but didn't get result please maintain part of code.Thanks

Comment: i have 4 imageview and try to click all of imageview to bind diffrent images like licence ,Rc,Profile pic from caemra of gallery

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void imageBrowse() {
if(camera){
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
}else{
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
}

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
            Uri picUri = data.getData();

            filePath = getPath(picUri);
            uri =picUri;
            Log.d("picUri", picUri.toString());
            Log.d("filePath", filePath);

            imageView.setImageURI(picUri);

        }

  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  

    }

}
```

Comment: when click on 2nd imageview to bind image from camera and gallery activityresult given error

Comment: i have 4 imageview and try to click all of imageview to bind diffrent images like licence ,Rc,Profile pic from caemra of gallery

Comment: please see mention Layout Image @Darshan Kachhadiya

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to refer this site, It's implementation is easy and straight forward...

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the perfectly working answer by @paras, if someone wants to include the Camera option also then please refer to the below steps:

1. Add a dialog box which pops-up on image click and asks to chose either Camera or Gallery:

   ```
   final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel"};

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotoActivity.this);
   builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
   builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {
               openCamera();
           } else if (items[item].equals("Gallery")) {
               openGallery();
           } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       }
   });
   builder.show();
   ```
2. Use this method to open the Camera intent:

   ```
   private void openCamera() {
       Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
   }
   ```
3. Now in the `onActivityResult()` method, include this to check whether the intent is from Camera:

   ```
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
       Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
       final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).get("data");
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   }
   ```